# DetachedCriteria convert to list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, detachedcriteria

When I tried to return result it will show return type mismatch. What can I do?

```
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<StudentDetail> getAllStudent(){
        DetachedCriteria.forClass(QrCodeList.class).add(Property.forName("userId")
                    .eq(
                              DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class).setProjection(Property.forName("id"))
                            )
                          );

        }
```

Comment: What is your exact error? Please add it to the question. I don't think there is enough detail for people to help here, so if you can add more detail, please do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this method returns `DetachedCriteria<QrCodeList>`.
To make it return `List` it should be like

```
    DetachedCriteria.forClass(QrCodeList.class).add(Property.forName("userId")
                .eq(DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class).setProjection(Property.forName("id")))
                      ).list()
```

But it would be `List<QrCodeList>`